# Python CSV export writing characters to new lines

Tags: list, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I have been using multiple code snippets to create a solution that will allow me to write a list of players in a football team to a csv file.

```
import csv

data = []
string = input("Team Name: ")
fName = string.replace(' ', '') + ".csv"

print("When you have entered all the players, press enter.")

# while loop that will continue allowing entering of players
done = False
while not done:
    a = input("Name of player: ")
    if a == "":
        done = True
    else:
        string += a + ','
        string += input("Age: ") + ','
        string += input("Position: ")

print (string)

file = open(fName, 'w')
output = csv.writer(file)

for row in string:
    tempRow = row
    output.writerow(tempRow)

file.close()

print("Team written to file.")
```

I would like the exported csv file to look like this:

```
player1,25,striker
player2,27,midfielder
```

and so on. However, when I check the exported csv file it looks more like this:

```
p
l
a
y
e
r
,
2
5
```

and so on.

Does anyone have an idea of where i'm going wrong?

Many thanks
Karl

Comment: No need for `tempRow` when writing into the CSV file. Also, you should open the file with the `newline=''` argument (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer -- you will find also the explanation there). It probably does not matter in your case, but it may matter one day... So, get used to that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `string` is a single string. It is not a list of strings. You are expecting it to be a list of strings when you are doing this:

```
for row in string:
```

When you iterate over a string, you are iterating over its characters. Which is why you are seeing a character per line.

Declare a list of strings. And append every string to it like this:

```
done = False
strings_list = []
while not done:
    string = ""
    a = input("Name of player: ")
    if a == "":
        done = True
    else:
        string += a + ','
        string += input("Age: ") + ','
        string += input("Position: ") + '\n'
        strings_list.append(string)
```

Now iterate over this `strings_list` and print to the output file. Since you are putting the delimiter (comma) yourself in the string, you do not need a csv writer.

```
a_file = open(fName, 'w')
for row in strings_list:
    print(row)
    a_file.write(row)
a_file.close()
```

**Note:**
`string` is a name of a standard module in Python. It is wise not to use this as a name of any variable in your program. Same goes for your variable `file`

Comment: Thanks for your help! i've done them changes and it works much better now. Although the output file now shows `p,l,a,y,e,r,1,2,5,s,t,r,i,k,e,r,`. Is there anyway to correct it so it displays as expected? Thanks

Comment: @karldou Check my updated answer. I have gotten rid of CSV write and added a new line character on the line ` string += input("Position: ") + '\n'`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much, it works perfectly now! reall appreciate it!